# dicebear api returns a 400 error code when trying to specify a skinColor

Tags: regex, api, http

im using the miniavs style in my app and im trying to specify a custom skin color

**The url i tried:**
https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/miniavs/:carim.svg?head=normal&body=tShirt&hair=balndess&mouth=default&eyes=normal&glassesProbability=0&mustacheProbability=0&blushesProbability=0&skinColor=#E3BEBE

**The message i got:**
"querystring.skinColor[0] should be equal to one of the allowed values, querystring.skinColor[0] should match pattern "^#([a-fA-F0-9]{3}|[a-fA-F0-9]{4}|[a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{8})$", querystring.skinColor[0] should match some schema in anyOf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the # symbol.

Try this instead:

https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/miniavs/:carim.svg?head=normal&body=tShirt&hair=balndess&mouth=default&eyes=normal&glassesProbability=0&mustacheProbability=0&blushesProbability=0&skinColor=%23E3BEBE